# How does C# handle variables in memory when their method is called multiple times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, memory, garbage-collection

First time asking here. My experience is only "advanced beginner". The question is about the variable storage in the memory due to an object instantiation in Unity.
 Need a bit to explain the setup:

In my scene, I instantiate an entire `starsystem`. The script can create up to 8 planets, each with up to 3 moons and 4 anchors (empty `gameObjects`). I do not change scenes, I only destroy the `starsystem` and instantiate the new one, so I need to ensure all old references are gone from memory. I want to be sure that I do not create a memory leak here by stuffing the memory with `gameObjects` that never get removed.

Below is the part of my script that instantiates the moons, can be called many times within a single system instantiation. The moon `gameObject` will be "returned" to the caller after instantiation and added to another variable created in the caller, which is it's official variable called `planetXMoonY`, and can only exist once per system and will be `nulled` before a new system instantiation.

In Version 1, I create the temporary variables within the method, and in version 2, I created them outside and first reset them before instantiating stuff.

How is this handled in memory ? Am I seeing it correct that in version 1 after a while there could be technically dozens or more `newMoon` `GameObjects` in memory ? Same name, but of course with separate instance `ID`, and I will filling up the memory.

What happens when the object `planetXMoonY` is destroyed ? When I understand it correctly, there is no more connection to the `newMoon` variable , but the `planetXMoonY` reference will be removed in time by the `GC()`. But will the `newMoon` variable ever be deleted from memory without a direct call setting it to `null` ?

So I thought maybe Version 2 is an improvement. Does it help to reset it to null first to ensure the `garbageCollector` removes all `newMoons` in time, since they aren't needed after returning the `gameObject`, there are just here for instantiation purpose. But am I still creating dozens in this way, or just one ?

I hope the question is clear enough. I seem to miss a bit of basic understanding in memory usage here. I think I'm missing a really important knowledge piece here on how to correctly and safely create variables, and I want to ensure my future workflow is improved. Thank you in advance for helping.

**B/R
Starman**

**Version 1:**

```
private GameObject InstantiateMoon(GameObject moon, GameObject planetSphere, float moonSphereRadius, float moonOrbit, float MoonOrbit_Y)
    {
    GameObject newMoon = Instantiate(moon, planetSphere.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, spheresContainer.transform) as GameObject;
    GameObject newMoonSphere = newMoon.transform.Find("MoonSphere").gameObject;
    newMoonSphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(moonSphereRadius, moonSphereRadius, moonSphereRadius);
    newMoonSphere.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,moonOrbit);
    newMoon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(MoonOrbit_Y, Vector3.up);
    DrawCircle orbitLine = newMoon.transform.Find("OrbitLine").gameObject.GetComponent<DrawCircle>();
    orbitLine.InitializeLine(moonOrbit);
    newMoon.transform.SetParent(planetSphere.transform);
    return newMoon;
    }
```

---

**Version 2**

```
private GameObject newMoon;
private GameObject newMoonSphere;
private DrawCircle orbitLine;

private GameObject InstantiateMoon2(GameObject moon, GameObject planetSphere, float moonSphereRadius, float moonOrbit, float MoonOrbit_Y)
    {
    newMoon = null;
    newMoonSphere = null;
    orbitLine = null;

    newMoon = Instantiate(moon, planetSphere.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, spheresContainer.transform) as GameObject;
    newMoonSphere = newMoon.transform.Find("MoonSphere").gameObject;
    newMoonSphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(moonSphereRadius, moonSphereRadius, moonSphereRadius);
    newMoonSphere.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,moonOrbit);
    newMoon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(MoonOrbit_Y, Vector3.up);
    orbitLine = newMoon.transform.Find("OrbitLine").gameObject.GetComponent<DrawCircle>();
    orbitLine.InitializeLine(moonOrbit);
    newMoon.transform.SetParent(planetSphere.transform);
    return newMoon;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, the 2nd function isn't an improvement.

When you do this:

```
newMoon = Instantiate(moon, planetSphere.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, spheresContainer.transform) as GameObject;
```

The previous value is dissassossiated from the `private newMoon` member and will be picked up by the garbage collector if it's not associated with another variable in your code.

The GC will pick an object when it is no logger used. If the object is not assigned to a variable then it is considered unused.

The variable itself in your first function, does not exist any more the moment the function ends. It returns a reference to the object and if that's not assigned anywhere, the object itself will be also picked up by the GC for disposal.

It mostly depends on what you do outside of the functions, instead of what happens inside.

If memory usage is a concern if yours, check the well known GoF flyweight pattern https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern which in your case, I think will help.

Comment: Thanks, I take a look into this link. So in short, as long as the same method is called from the existing script instance (there is only one instance for the instantiation script) there will be always be one "newMoon" variable, and it cease to exist after the function ends as you said. In that case, I guess I'm save I can keep version 1, it reads a bit smoother. Sorry, can't upvote your answer because I'm a new user ;)

Comment: To clarify, in c# yes this true.  In Unity, all Unity objects created via new or instantiated will be referenced by its object manager and the only way to get the GC to pick it up is to call destroy, so Unity's Object manager knows you are done with it, and will stop referencing it so the GC will pick it up.

Comment: Sounds logic. So my destruction of the starsystem is safe. But what about the instantiation "new moon" object. The method returns the object and i store it inside a variable which will be destroyed later. Is the newMoon part of the object manager, or is this purely a c# thing  in the script and the objectmanager doesn't care about this object ?.

Comment: When you call instantiate on it yes, however, the second you call destroy on it Unity doesn't care if you ave a reference stored its GC will still pick it up.

Comment: @Starman001 here is a link that goes indepth into Unity's GC https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html

Comment: Thank you guys. Lot of valuable information, and I think what Athanasios said above is my key answer. The variable cease to exist once the method will be left. I count on that. For my starsystem itself, i will call a destroy method that set's the planets and moons to "null", just to be 100% sure, since the gameobject themselve will be destroyed too via a code call..